# Registering Load Balancer Errors In Lambda Metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-application-load-balancer

I currently have a solution running in AWS that uses the following workflow.

SQS => Lambda => ApplicationLoadBalancer => Target group => Fargate

This solution works great, but errors that are registered in the load balancer, hence coming from the service in Fargate, are not reflected in the Lambda function.

Since the Lambda request is registered as a `200`, the message is removed from the queue, when it should really be added back to the queue, or sent to my dead letter queue.

**To clarify, when an error occurs, I can see it in my load balancer metrics, just not my lambda function.**

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the funcionality of SQS, the message gets removed if the lambda exited with success status (no errors inside of execution). Now back to the problem i guess on your code you need to ensure the response status from your LoadBalancer is correct.

The aproach i'll use is if the Lambda gets a error from the LoadBalancer (statuscode != 200) throw a exception to cause fail execution of lambda. When this happens the message will be retried some times (these times of deliveries you configure before message goes to dead-letter queue) and when retries are exahusted the message gets removed from original queue and send to dead-letter.